# Beefy fails to find a git dependency

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'm trying to use [PicoModal](https://github.com/d3x7r0/PicoModal) in a client-side JavaScript app using [Beefy](http://didact.us/beefy/) for local development. I have two dependencies on `git` reopsitories in `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "dagre-d3": "git://github.com/knowledge-graph/dagre-d3.git#master",
    "PicoModal": "git://github.com/d3x7r0/PicoModal.git#master",
    ...
```

But when I try to do this:

```
var dagreD3 = require('dagre-d3');
var modal = require('PicoModal');
```

I get the following error from Beefy:

```
Error: module "PicoModal" not found from "c:\\dev\\..."
```

So of these two identically set-up module definitions, one of them is not found by `require`. What could be causing this module to fail? Is it a problem with the `package.json` definition? The package does define `"name": "PicoModal"`, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about `npm` to know if something else could be confusing it. At the moment, I can write:

```
var modal = require('../node_modules/PicoModal/src/picoModal.js');
```

And the module will be found and everything will work correctly. But... this seems like a poor solution!